# jQuery/ColdFusion Ajax Creating Session Variable

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to create a Single Page Application using ColdFusion and JQuery. I am trying to have a (Print Labels) button that when it is clicked it will open up a bootstrap modal asking a question "Please enter label start number:" This textbox I want to somehow create a session variable that may be used on the (dealerlabels.pdf) pdf that opens  Upon hit of Accept of the Bootstrap Modal. In the console.log(data) I am getting the correct response showing the number that was entered into $("#LabelNum") but I am unable to create the session variable. When I do a cfdump nothing exists in the struct. Will someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/1zka4soy/13/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // What happens when a user hits the "Accept" button on the dealer form
    $(".label_accept").click(function () {
        $('#LabelMaker').modal('hide');

    });

    $('#labelForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            // the location of the CFC to run
            url: "index_proxy.cfm",
            // send a GET HTTP operation
            type: "post",
            // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
            dataType: "json",
            // send the data to the CFC
            data: $('#labelForm').serialize(),
            // this gets the data returned on success
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data !== "") {     
                    var link = "DealerLabels.cfm";
                    window.open(link,'newStuff'); 
                }
            }, 
            // this runs if an error
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**index_proxy.cfm**

```
<cfset labelNum = form.LabelNum >
<cfoutput> #labelNum# </Cfoutput>


<!---Initial check to see if we have a core structure to store our data.--->
<cfif not structKeyExists(session, "dealerwork")>
    <cfset session.dealerwork = {}>
</cfif>
<!--- initial defaults for the first section --->
<cfif not structKeyExists(session.checkout, "labels")>
    <cfset session.dealerwork.labels= {LabelNum=""}>
</cfif>
<!---form fields will default according to session values---> 
<cfparam name="#labelNum#" default="#session.dealerwork.labels.LabelNum#">

<cfset errors = []>
    <cfif not arrayLen(errors)>
<cfset session.dealerwork.labels = {LabelNum=form.LabelNum}>
</cfif>
```

**DealerLabels.cfm**

```
<cfset LabelNum = #session.dealerwork.labels.LabelNum#>

<cfset tempFilePath = "/mytemppath.pdf">
<cfpdfform source="forms/DealerLabel.pdf" action="populate" destination="#tempFilePath#">

    <cfpdfformparam name="One" value="#LabelNum#">
</cfpdfform>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=LabelMaker.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#tempFilePath#" deleteFile="true">
```

**Application.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent>


<cfset this.datasource = "DealerTracking" >
<cfset this.name = "DealerTracking">
<cfset this.sessionManagement = "true">
<cfset this.sessionTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,5,0,0)#">
<cfset this.clientManagement = "false">
<cfset this.loginStorage = "session">
<cfset this.setDomainCookies = "true">
<cfset this.scriptProtect = "true">
<cfset this.applicationTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,5,0,0)#">

<cffunction name="onError" returntype="void"> 
    <cfargument name="Exception" required="true" >
    <cfargument name="EventName" required="true" type="string" >
    <cfif arguments.EventName eq "true">
        <cflog text="Error occurred: #arguments.exception#: #arguments.EventName#" type="error" file="#this.name#" > 
    <cfelse>
        <cflog text="Error occurred: #arguments.exception#" type="error" file="#this.name#" > 
    </cfif> 
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returntype="boolean"> 
    <cfset application.activeSessions = 0>
    <cflog text="The Dealer Tracking application has started." type="information" file="#this.name#" > 
    <cfreturn true> 
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="onApplicationEnd" returntype="void"> 
    <cfargument name="appScope" required = "true" >
    <cflog text="The Dealer Tracking application shut down." type="information" file="#this.name#" > 
</cffunction> 


</cfcomponent>
```

**CFDUMP on DealerLabels.cfm**
[image]

Comment: What about your Application.cfc - did you set up session management?

Comment: Where are you doing you dump?  The `cfheader` and `cfcontent` tags will prevent you from seeing anything useful.

Comment: From the code you shared it doesn't look like you are returning anything from `index_proxy.cfm`. That is okay but I would expect the `console.log(data)` in your success function to be empty. **EDIT** Never mind I see a `cfoutput` in there now.

Comment: disregard my previous comment, I see that you are indeed outputting the number which gets returned from the AJAX call. What do you get when you cfdump the session in DealerLabels.cfm? Add a cfabort after the cfdump to stop any further processing so you can see the dump.

Comment: So you don't see the `session.dealerwork.labels` structure in your session dump?

Comment: Sorry, had to step away for a bit. Have you tried deleting your cookies? Or tried different browsers to see if the issue persists?  If you dump the session.sessionid from the index_proxy.cfm file and the DealerLabels.cfm file do they have the same value or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you simply do what you say you want to do, create a session variable.  In index_proxy.cfm you have this:

```
<cfset labelNum = form.LabelNum >
```

In addition to or instead of that, do this:

```
<cfset session.dealerwork.labels.labelNum = form.LabelNum >
```

Comment: Well that was easy. I wonder why this code `<cfset session.dealerwork.labels = {LabelNum=form.LabelNum}>` did not work?